# Error: no matching function for call to BufferIO::open(const char*&, int)

Tags: c++, file, flags

//Displayed Error message in eclipse cdt.

```
- Syntax error
    - candidate is:
    - no matching function for call to ‘BufferIO::open(const char*&, 
     int)’
```

```
//BufferIO::BufferIO(const char* filename) {

    // trying to open a a file
    if( (mfile = int open(filename, O_RDONLY | O_DIRECT)) == -1) {
        STDERR("opening file failed");
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's the question?

Comment: What is `mfile = int open(...)` supposed to mean?

Comment: What's the "int" doing before "open"? Also, please post complete error messages.

Comment: How is the function declared? You link with the source/object file the function is in?

Comment: By the way, take a look at the function signature, and what the compiler expects (what you're being told in the error message). Compare those two signatures. Compare both with the *declaration*. Compare all to the *definition*.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really enough information in your posting to provide a full answer; however, if I had to guess, I would assume that you're trying to either call the C function open() or perhaps fstream::open()  BUT, you have already declared and/or defined a BufferIO::open() function.   If that guess is correct, then you have namespace issues.

Or, if you're actually TRYING to call BufferIO::open(), then you need to provide us with the source and/or declaration so we can help you determine why it doesn't match.